# Skip some rows which are in the end of the uploaded dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I am uploading and reading a text file in my shiny app. Here is how it is getting read in the shiny app:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], skip = 15, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    return(df)
  })
```

Now, it is really easy to skip some initial rows from the dataset. One can directly include `skip` argument in the `read.table` and instruct how many lines they want to skip.

Is there any way we can skip some rows which are at the end of the dataset. Say, I want to skip the last 15 rows from the uploaded dataset.

Comment: if you know how many rows there are, you could use additional parameter ```nrows = rows -15```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `head` with a negative index:

```
df <- data.frame(row = 1:20)
df
head(df,-15)

  row
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of rows of the file, then `data.table::fread()` has a `nrows=` argument, so this will do:

```
data.table::fread("file", nrows = 100) # file has 115 rows
```

More troublesome when you don't know the number of rows but want the last 15 rows to be gone, one maybe a little inefficient way is:

```
tmp <- readLines(file)
nr <- length(tmp)
data.table::fread("file", nrows = nr-15)
```

**Update:** `read.table()` also has `nrows=` argument and does the same job too!

Comment: Ben Toh, User doesn't always know the number of rows of the file as they are variable in each and every file.

Comment: Yeah that's what the second solution was for. It allows you to check the length of the file before reading it in.